# Как нарисовать указанным шрифтом?

Tags: java, android

Делаю так:

```
p.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SKYWORK.TTF"));
canvas.drawText("!@#$%^&*123OPQW7890", 200, 200, p);
```

Шрифт прописан: `assets/fonts/SKYWORK.TTF`

Результат: рисует символы, но не тем шрифтом, который указал.

Вопрос: что не так делаю?

Comment: проверьте, создается ли `Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SKYWORK.TTF")`.

Comment: А как проверить создался или нет?

Comment: Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SKYWORK.TTF"); if(font != null) {//то создался}

Comment: Проверил - font создался. В чем еще может быть проблема?

Comment: Получилось. Просто что-то со шрифтом было. Проверил на другом и все заработало.

Comment: Спасибо всем, кто откликнулся!